# html css js Keep sidebar with drop down links open on different pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a portfolio website of my OJT experience. It's a project that is due 3 days and nearly complete.

My problem is that I'd like to keep the sidebar navigation open as well as the drop down links when I open a different page. For example, if I am on the Home page and I clicked the Rationale page on the sidebar, I'm taken to the Rationale page with the sidebar and drop down still open from the previous page (Home page in this example). I need the same for every page. If I can, I'd like to keep the current codes as much as possible, with just the new codes added on.

Sorry if the codes are messy, I had to relearn HTML and CSS for this project since I'm not very familiar and don't have much experience with web developing. Thank you.

HTML sidebar and dropdown

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <nav id='navigation' class="navigation">
        <div id="menuToggle" class="menuToggle">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
                <ul id="menu">

                    <button class="dropdown-btn">Introduction 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                          <div class="dropdown-container">
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#rationale">Rationale</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#work-expectation">Work Expectation</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#contact-details">Contact Details</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#company-profile">Company Profile</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#company-size">Company Size</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#nature-business">Nature of Business</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#divisions">Divisions/Departments</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#organizational-chart">Organizational Chart</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/introduction/intro.html#company-pics0">Pictures of the Company</a>
                          </div>                              

                    <button class="dropdown-btn">Observation
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                          <div class="dropdown-container">
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/observation/observe.html#SWOT">SWOT Analysis</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/observation/observe.html#overall-observations">Overall Observation</a>
                          </div>

                    <button class="dropdown-btn">Anecdotal Reports 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                          <div class="dropdown-container">
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports/anecreport.html">Periodic Reports</a>
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports2/anecreport2.html#prof-train">Professional Experiences and Training</a>
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports2/anecreport2.html#tasks-assign">Tasks and Assignments</a>
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports2/anecreport2.html#prob-enc">Problems Encountered</a>
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports2/anecreport2.html#out-ach">Outstanding Achievements</a>
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports2/anecreport2.html#sal-prac">Salient Practices</a>
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports2/anecreport2.html#rel-cho">Relevance of the Chosen Training</a>
                            <a href="F:/website-ojt/anecdotalreports2/anecreport2.html#overall-exp">Overall Experiences</a>
                          </div>

                    <button class="dropdown-btn">Appendix 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                          <div class="dropdown-container">
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/appendix/appendix.html#reco-lett">Practicum Recommendation Letter</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/appendix/appendix.html#liab-waiv">Agreement & Liability Waiver</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/appendix/appendix.html#eval-repo">Performance Evaluation Report</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/appendix/appendix.html#cert-hour">Certificate of Hours Worked</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/appendix/appendix.html#atte-sum0">Attendance Summary</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/appendix/appendix.html#pics-work">Pictures while in Actual Work</a>
                              <a href="F:/website-ojt/appendix/appendix.html#prof-resu">Professional Resume</a>
                         </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <script src="intro.js"></script>
</div>
```

CSS to style the sidebar

```
#menu a{
  padding:10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
#menu a:hover{
  color:rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
#menuToggle::before{
  /* display:block;
  position: absolute; 
  content: "OJT Portfolio";
  width:144px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color:#f2f2f2;
  top: 1px;
  right: 44px; */
}
#menuToggle
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 22px;
right: 22px;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
#menuToggle input
{
display: block;
width: 40px;
height: 32px;
position: absolute;
top: -7px;
left: -5px;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#menuToggle span
{
display: block;
width: 33px;
height: 4px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
position: relative;
background: #cdcdcd;
border-radius: 3px;
z-index: 1;
transform-origin: 4px 0px;
transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
            background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
            opacity 0.55s ease;
}
#menuToggle span:first-child
{
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
opacity: 1;
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
background: #232323;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
opacity: 0;
transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
opacity: 1;
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#menu
{
position: absolute;
height: 100vh;
width: 300px;
padding-bottom: 100%;
margin: -100px 0 0 0;
padding: 40px;
padding-top: 167px;
padding-left: 20px;
right: -60px;
background: #181818;
list-style-type: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
transform: translate(100%, 0);
transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}
#menu li
{
padding: 10px 0;
/* padding:0 10px 0 0; */
font-size: 22px;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown-btn {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  padding: 22px 22px 22px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #818181;
}
.active {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Basically you need to check which page your on and compare it to the navigation and give the correct element an active CSS style.

Would be easier with PHP, than Javascript  :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately im not skilled enough in CSS to know which class/id to do it for, and ive turned in the project already. but i will definitely keep this in mind for the future.